# Sum of first even n numbers that are divisible by 3 using while loop

Tags: java, loops, sum

the sum of the first N even numbers that are also divisible by 3. So if the input was 5, the first N even numbers are 0, 2, 4, 6, 8. Of those 5 numbers, only 6 is divisible by 3, so the output would be 6.
This is what I have attempted so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise1_3 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      int n = sc.nextInt();
      int sum = 0;

      int count=0;

      while(count<n){
         // I am stuck here
         System.out.print(sum+" ");
         sum=sum+2;
         count++;
      }

   }
}
```

```
input: 5
// (0, 2, 4, 6, 8) only 6 divides by 3 thus
output: 6
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple issues with your code:

1. You are always adding 2 to the sum, rather than adding the numbers that are divisible by three.
2. You are never checking to see if the number is divisible by three. You can check that using code like `n % 3 == 0`.

Try this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise1_3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Read the input.
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        // Loop over the first n even numbers.
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        while (count < n) {
            int nextEven = 2 * count;

            // If the number is divisible by 3, then add to the running sum.
            if (nextEven % 3 == 0) {
                sum += nextEven;
            }

            count++;
        }

        // Print the output.
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: OP's original question is a little unclear, so I think you and I are just interpreting it differently. I interpreted it as the sum of the first N even numbers that are also divisible by 3. So if the input was 5, the first N even numbers are 0, 2, 4, 6, 8. Of those 5 numbers, only 6 is divisible by 3, so the output would be 6.

Comment: yes that's right and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find a numbers divisible by two numbers, then you need to find the highest common factor(HCF- Incase of 2 and 3, it will 6) of those numbers and incrementally check whether each number is divisible by the HCF.

To reduce time complexity further, once we have found a number which is divisible by HCF, we can increment the number by HCF(6, 12, 18 and so on in this case) and find the sum of those numbers.